# dodecahedron proof on number of vertices, edges, and faces

Tags: geometry

Find, with a proof, the number of vertices, edges, and faces of a dodecahedron.

Its is clear that their are $20$ vertices, $30$ edges, and $12$ faces. I am not sure how to prove this though.

Comment: To prove those facts you'll need to start with some definition of dodecahedron.  The name itself means twelve-sided.

Comment: Do you mean a regular dodecahedron?

Comment: I think the most instructive procedure, and I did this as a child, is to make one out of thin cardboard and tape along the edges, then get a felt-tip marker and number everything of interest. Quickest to get a round protractor and mark every $72^\circ$ around a circle to get a regular pentagon. You need twelve of those.

Answer (score 2):

For vertices, there are $12$ faces times $5$ vertices per face but since each face is connected to $3$ vertices it is counted three times. Therefore, $V = 12\times 5 \div 3 = 20$.

For edges, there are $12$ faces times $5$ edges per face but since each edge joins $2$ faces it is counted twice. Therefore, $E = 12\times 5 \div 2 = 30$.

Do you see the pattern? Try the same exercise with a tetrahedron and an octahedron to see if you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on what you are allowed to assume.  [This](http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/platonic-solids-and-eulers-formula-for-polyhedra/) might be helpful.